# Is there a way to test for null on all columns in a wildcard select?

Tags: mysql

PSEUDO:

```
select * from foo where [every column is not null]
```

Is there a way to do this without specifying the actual column names?

Comment: Afraid not - you've got to name them all.

Comment: Just a question why you don't know the names of your table?

Comment: @Ankit, As it happens I'm working with a dynamic derived table which can have all sorts of columns and all sorts of names. Of course I can construct an elaborate and ugly string of ANDs but was hoping to avoid that (and I think you mean the names of my columns).

Comment: @EdGibbs, you may as well post that as an answer and I'll select it.  If it's correct, may as well be here for posterity in case someone else stumbles across it.

Comment: can't test here, but is `CONCAT( * )` valid syntax? If one value is NULL, it returns NULL.

Comment: `count(*)` counts even `null` rows, `count(column)` does not. But I can't think of something to get that wrapped up.

Comment: So you want to find *rows* where every *column* is null? In a table with an arbitrary name? Just making sure...

Comment: @ethrbunny is *not* NULL

Comment: Dr.Dredel - you're too kind, but my comment is only correct in the narrow syntactical sense that you do have to name all the columns. @peterm went the extra mile to show *how* you can name them all without having to type them all; it's probably as close to a `WHERE * IS NOT NULL` as anyone will get.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A possible solution that I can think of involves using dynamic-SQL

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(column_name SEPARATOR ' IS NOT NULL AND ')
   INTO @sql
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 WHERE table_schema = SCHEMA()
   AND table_name = 'foo'
 GROUP BY table_name;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM foo WHERE ', @sql, ' IS NOT NULL');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2bf0/2)** demo

---

*Obviously it can be wrapped into a stored procedure with a parameter for a table name*

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_select_all_not_null(IN tbl_name VARCHAR(64))
BEGIN
  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(column_name SEPARATOR ' IS NOT NULL AND ')
     INTO @sql
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
   WHERE table_schema = SCHEMA()
     AND table_name = tbl_name
   GROUP BY table_name;

  SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', tbl_name, ' WHERE ', @sql, ' IS NOT NULL');

  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
DELIMITER ;
```

And then use it

```
CALL sp_select_all_not_null('foo');
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/43ab9/1)** demo for that

Comment: @Dr.Dredel You're more than welcome :) Give it a spin. You can also take a look at sqlfiddle example that I've posted.